# Kafka topic partition and Spark executor mapping

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am using spark streaming with kafka topic. topic is created with 5 partitions. My all messages are published to the kafka topic using tablename as key. 
Given this i assume all messages for that table should goto the same partition. 
But i notice in the spark log messages for same table sometimes goes to executor's node-1 and sometime goes to executor's node-2.

I am running code in yarn-cluster mode using following command:

```
spark-submit --name DataProcessor --master yarn-cluster --files /opt/ETL_JAR/executor-log4j-spark.xml,/opt/ETL_JAR/driver-log4j-spark.xml,/opt/ETL_JAR/application.properties --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=driver-log4j-spark.xml" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=executor-log4j-spark.xml" --class com.test.DataProcessor /opt/ETL_JAR/etl-all-1.0.jar
```

and this submission creates 1 driver lets say on node-1 and 2 executors on node-1 and node-2.

I don't want node-1 and node-2 executors to read the same partition. but this is happening

Also tried following configuration to specify consumer group but no difference.

```
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "app1");
```

This is how we are creating the stream using createDirectStream method 
*Not through zookeeper.

```
    HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "largest");
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "app1");

        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                jssc, 
                String.class, 
                String.class,
                StringDecoder.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                kafkaParams, 
                topicsSet
        );
```

Complete Code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContextFactory;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class DataProcessor2 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3071125481526170241L;

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("DataProcessor");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String sparkCheckPointDir = ApplicationProperties.getProperty(Consts.SPARK_CHECKPOINTING_DIR);
        DataProcessorContextFactory3 factory = new DataProcessorContextFactory3();
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate(sparkCheckPointDir, factory);

        // Start the process
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }

}

class DataProcessorContextFactory3 implements JavaStreamingContextFactory, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6070911284191531450L;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataProcessorContextFactory.class);

    DataProcessorContextFactory3() {
    }

    @Override
    public JavaStreamingContext create() {
        logger.debug("creating new context..!");

        final String brokers = ApplicationProperties.getProperty(Consts.KAFKA_BROKERS_NAME);
        final String topic = ApplicationProperties.getProperty(Consts.KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME);
        final String app = "app1";
        final String offset = ApplicationProperties.getProperty(Consts.KAFKA_CONSUMER_OFFSET, "largest");

        logger.debug("Data processing configuration. brokers={}, topic={}, app={}, offset={}", brokers, topic, app,
                offset);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(brokers) || StringUtils.isBlank(topic) || StringUtils.isBlank(app)) {
            System.err.println("Usage: DataProcessor <brokers> <topic>\n" + Consts.KAFKA_BROKERS_NAME
                    + " is a list of one or more Kafka brokers separated by comma\n" + Consts.KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME
                    + " is a kafka topic to consume from \n\n\n");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        final String majorVersion = "1.0";
        final String minorVersion = "3";
        final String version = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion;
        final String applicationName = "DataProcessor-" + topic + "-" + version;
        // for dev environment
         SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName(applicationName);
        // for cluster environment
        //SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(applicationName);
        final long sparkBatchDuration = Long
                .valueOf(ApplicationProperties.getProperty(Consts.SPARK_BATCH_DURATION, "10"));

        final String sparkCheckPointDir = ApplicationProperties.getProperty(Consts.SPARK_CHECKPOINTING_DIR);

        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(sparkBatchDuration));
        logger.debug("setting checkpoint directory={}", sparkCheckPointDir);
        jssc.checkpoint(sparkCheckPointDir);

        HashSet<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(topic.split(",")));

        HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", offset);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "app1");

//          @formatter:off
            JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    jssc, 
                    String.class, 
                    String.class,
                    StringDecoder.class, 
                    StringDecoder.class, 
                    kafkaParams, 
                    topicsSet
            );
//          @formatter:on
        processRDD(messages, app);
        return jssc;
    }

    private void processRDD(JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages, final String app) {
        JavaDStream<MsgStruct> rdd = messages.map(new MessageProcessFunction());

        rdd.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<MsgStruct>, Void>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 250647626267731218L;

            @Override
            public Void call(JavaRDD<MsgStruct> currentRdd) throws Exception {
                if (!currentRdd.isEmpty()) {
                    logger.debug("Receive RDD. Create JobDispatcherFunction at HOST={}", FunctionUtil.getHostName());
                    currentRdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<MsgStruct>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void call(Iterator<MsgStruct> arg0) throws Exception {
                            while(arg0.hasNext()){
                                System.out.println(arg0.next().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    logger.debug("Current RDD is empty.");
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
    public static class MessageProcessFunction implements Function<Tuple2<String, String>, MsgStruct> {
        @Override
        public MsgStruct call(Tuple2<String, String> data) throws Exception {
            String message = data._2();
            System.out.println("message:"+message);
            return MsgStruct.parse(message);
        }

    }
    public static class MsgStruct implements Serializable{
        private String message;
        public static MsgStruct parse(String msg){
            MsgStruct m = new MsgStruct();
            m.message = msg;
            return m;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return "content inside="+message;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `DirectStream` approach it's a correct assumption that messages sent to a Kafka partition will land in the same Spark partition.

What we cannot assume is that each Spark partition will be processed by the same Spark worker each time.  On each batch interval, Spark task are created for each `OffsetRange` for each partition and sent to the cluster for processing, landing on some available worker.

What you are looking for partition locality.  The only [partition locality that the direct kafka consumer supports](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaRDD.scala#L107) is the kafka host containing the offset range being processed in the case that you Spark and Kafka deployements are colocated; but that's a deployment topology that I don't see very often.

In case that your requirements dictate the need to have host locality, you should look into [Apache Samza](http://samza.apache.org/) or [Kafka Streams](http://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple).

Answer (score 4):

According to [Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.10.0 or higher)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html), you can specify an explicit mapping of partitions to **hosts**.

Assume you have two hosts(h1 and h2), and the Kafka topic `topic-name` has three partitions. The following critical code will show you how to map a specified partition to a host in Java.

```
Map<TopicPartition, String> partitionMapToHost = new HashMap<>();
// partition 0 -> h1, partition 1 and 2 -> h2
partitionMapToHost.put(new TopicPartition("topic-name", 0), "h1");
partitionMapToHost.put(new TopicPartition("topic-name", 1), "h2");
partitionMapToHost.put(new TopicPartition("topic-name", 2), "h2");
List<String> topicCollection = Arrays.asList("topic-name");
Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HasMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.0.0.2:9092,10.0.0.3:9092");
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "group-id-name");
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferFixed(partitionMapToHost), // PreferFixed is the key
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topicCollection, kafkaParams));
```

You can also use `LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent()`, which distribute partitions evenly across available **executors**, and assure that a specified partition is only consumed by a specified executor.